How to get link details on click [FLIPBOOK]?
I am using this jquery plugins to create flipbook from PDF.
This is a working example.
Every page might have a clickable link which create like this
<a href="abcd.com" class="internalLink" data-page="5">click</a>

I want to write a code to get href when someone click on this link.
Below code was written in there library but it is not used anywhere.
{
    book.onPageLinkClick = function (link) {
        console.log('onPageLinkClick')
        var id = link.dataset.bookid;
        var page = link.dataset.page;
        if (page) {
            //book.books[id].goToPage(Number(page));
        }
        console.log(page, link.dataset.url)
        var _url = link.dataset.url;
        if (_url) {
            //window.open(_url, '_blank');
        }
    };
}

IF anyone has done this before or know how can I achieve this, Please let me know.
Thanks
